# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zijieyu'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

I just installed mysql and set the path. But after I write mysql -v in my Mac terminal, it shows "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zijieyu'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". I think it should be root@localhost. And I can use mysql -u root -p to use database. Please tell me how to solve this problem? I just want to set default database is root not zijieyu.

Comment: Does `zijieyu` means anything to you?

Comment: "root" or "zijieyu" is not the database, it's the username you are trying to connect. When you login with your normal account "zijieyu" and use `mysql` without the `-u` switch it will use the current user as the login name. If you don't want that use the `-u` switch to use a different login name.

Comment: Oh thank you! I got it!